# How do I profile release (not debug) build of a react-native app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm able to launch `*profile*` from a debug build. But the debug build is not very useful for profiling (it contains a lot of debug stuff). Is there a way to launch `*perf monitor*`, `*systrace*`, and a correct work of `*profile*` in Chrome?